# How to load an HTML template from a tpl.js file using Require.js

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

First I'm not sure if Backbone is the library that I should be using so please note that.

I'm building a static content site that's composed of about 17 pages.

The first question you may be wondering is: Why use Backbone if there isn't any dynamic content on the site?

The only good answer I have to that is there still are some repeatable elements of the of page like Footer and some that may have only changes in things like the "title" as in the case of a Header. So I would like to practice DRY principles in this regard.

Also I want to learn Backbone so to me this is a soft step in the right direction of putting it all together in my head.

I want to use handlebars for templating but haven't found one good tutorial on how to call a template {{Footer}} inside of my index.html file that is being called from some other external.js file.

In other words I want my templates in individual .js files and be able to call them into my index.html file and I can't find a good way to do that.

Any suggestions just based on my Footer example, as I think I could figure it out from there.

Thank you.

UPDATE:

Here is what I would ideally like my index page to look like:

Index.html where I'm trying to pull MainView which has HeaderView and FooterView as partials inside of it.

```
<body>

    <div id="container">
        <!-- BODY WRAPPER -->
        <section class="body-wrapper">

            <div class="header-container" id="home">
                <div class="header-nav-container">
                    {{> header}}
                </div>
            </div>


            <section class="home-content">
                {{> home-content}}
            </section>


            <section class="footer-container">
                {{> footer}}
            </section>

        </section>
        <!-- /.body-wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- /#container -->

    <script data-main="js/config" src="js/libs/require.js"></script>

</body>
```

HomeContentView: views/homeContentView.js

```
define(
  ['jquery','underscore','backbone' , 'text!/templates/main.tpl.html' 'text!/templates/home-content.tpl.html'],
  function($, _, Backbone, mainTemplate, homeContentTemplate){

    handlebars.registerPartial('home-content' , homeContentTemplate);

    var template = handlebars.compile()

    var HomeContentView = Backbone.View.extend({
      el      : $('#content'),
      render  : function() {
        this.$el.html(homeContentTemplate);
      }

    });

    return HomeView;
});
```

Header partials: views/headerView.js

```
define(
  ['jquery' , 'underscore' , 'backbone' , 'handlebars' , 'text!/templates/main.tpl.html' , 'text!/templates/header.tpl.html'],

  function($, _, Backbone, Handlebars, mainTemplate, headerTemplate){

    handlebars.registerPartial('header' , headerTemplate);

    var template = handlebars.compile()

   var HeaderView = Backbone.View.extend({
      el      : $('#header'),
      render  : function() {
        this.$el.append(headerTemplate);
      }

    });

    return HeaderView;
});
```

Footer view: views/footerView.js

```
define(
  ['jquery','underscore','backbone' , 'text!/templates/main.tpl.html' , 'text!/templates/footer.tpl.html'],
  function($, _, Backbone, mainTemplate, footerTemplate){

    handlebars.registerPartial('footer' , footerTemplate);

    var template = handlebars.compile()

    var FooterView = Backbone.View.extend({
      el      : $('#footer'),

      render  : function() {
        this.$el.html(footerTemplate);
      }

    });

    return FooterView;
});
```

Main View that holds Header and Footer partials: views/mainView.js

```
define(
  ['jquery','underscore','backbone' , 'index.html' 'text!/templates/main.tpl.html'],
  function($, _, Backbone, homeTemplate, mainTemplate){

    handlebars.registerPartial('main' , mainTemplate);

    var template = handlebars.compile()

    var MainView = Backbone.View.extend({
      el      : $('.home-content'),

      render  : function() {
        this.$el.html(mainTemplate);
      }

    });

    return MainView;
});
```

Router.js

```
define(

  ['jquery',
   'underscore',
   'backbone',
   'views/MainView'
   'views/HomeContentView',
   'views/HeaderView',
   'views/FooterView',
   'models/FeatureModel',
   'collections/FeatureCollection'],

  function($, _, Backbone, MainView, HomeConentView, HeaderView, FooterView, FeatureModel, FeatureCollection){

  var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
      ''                 : 'home', //#index
      '/feature/:page'   : 'featurePage',
      '*actions'         : 'defaultAction'
    }

  });

  var initialize = function(options) {

    var appView = options.appView;
    var router = new AppRouter(options);

    router.on('home', function(){

      var mainView = new MainView();
      mainView.render();
    });

    router.on('route:defaultAction', function(actions){

      var homeContentView = new HomeContentView();
      homeContentView.render();
    });

    router.on('support', function(){

      var supportView = new SupportView();
      supportView.render();
    });

    var headerView = new HeaderView();

    var footerView = new FooterView();

    Backbone.history.start();

  };
  return {
    initialize: initialize
  };

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the [text plugin](https://github.com/requirejs/text) for require.js to load your templates as a raw text and use the `Handlebars.registerPartial` method to store the template and make it available to use for other templates as a partial.

The code would look like that:

```
define(['handlebars', 'text!main.tpl.html','text!footer.tpl.html'],
    function(handlebars, mainTpl, footerTpl ){

    // Register the footer's template as a partial.
    handlebars.registerPartial('footer', footerTpl);

    // Compile the main template. The footer is included.
    var template = handlebars.compile(mainTpl);

    // ... use the template ...
});
```

As for your main template, you just need to specify where the footer template would go.

```
<section>
    Something...
    {{> footer}}
</section>
```

(Note the ">" that indicates partials.)

Comment: so here's my footer code where would I being to register the partial? Would it be before I declare the view? Or am I mixing up patterns here? `define(
  ['jquery','underscore','backbone' , 'text!/templates/footer.tpl.html'],
  function($, _, Backbone, footerTemplate){

    var FooterView = Backbone.View.extend({
      el      : $('#footer'),

      render  : function() {
        this.$el.html(footerTemplate);
      }

    });

    return FooterView;
}); `

Comment: Also if this is supposedly on the my views/footer.js file why would I also call in my "mainTpl"? Is that to say if I wanted to create a header template too that I would have to include that as well inside of some other greater template? So in other words it's better to create a main general template and just call the header and footer into the main template as a partial? Would that then mean I could just create the content areas as partials and call them into the main template? Sorry for so many questions. Thank you.

Comment: Also how would i make the main.tpl.html be the index.html page?